# Firebase value not being updated?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update values in firebase using the below method. The adding of likes works fine. But I want to add the UID of the person who liked in another node. Thus I try to use the first firebase update at the top of the function.

**The problem is however that the first fire update does not seem to run. How do I fix this?**

```
func addLike(index: Int) {
        self.databaseRef.child("Likes").child((self.post?.user.userID)!).child(self.postPath).child((self.post?)!).updateChildValues([Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid : true])

        databaseRef.child("MediaStats").child((post?.user.userID)!).child(postPath).child((post?)!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            var valLikes = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "likes").value!

            if valLikes is NSNull {
                self.databaseRef.child("MediaStats").child((self.post?.user.userID)!).child(self.postPath).child((self.post?)!).updateChildValues(["likes" : 1])

            } else {
                valLikes = (valLikes as! Int) + 1                    self.databaseRef.child("MediaStats").child((self.post?.user.userID)!).child(self.postPath).child((self.post?)!).updateChildValues(["likes" : valLikes])
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `postPath` has multiple child branch names in it to make it a path. Did you mean to refer to the post's uid instead? If not, would you mind posting a screen shot of your branch for `Likes` ? What are the values for `postPath` and `post?.media[index].numberMedia`

Also, the line:

```
self.databaseRef.child("Likes").child((self.post?.user.userID)!).child(self.postPath).child((self.post?.media[index].numberMedia)!).updateChildValues([Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid : true])
```

finds a child branch that's like 4 branches deep. Either you aren't fanning your data structure out or maybe you're approaching finding the value incorrectly?

**EDIT**:

Try swapping out

```
.updateChildValues([Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid : true])
```

for

```
.child(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid).setValue(true)
```

Comment: DB Structure looks like:

   Likes
     UID
      PostID
         Media#
           UID: true;

Comment: So is postPath equal to postID?

Comment: Yes postpath is equal to postID

Comment: please see edit, it adds the uid : true child to the branch. The `.updateChildValues()` might not have worked because the current userId wasn't a child branch yet.